# Given a list [9,2,11].Find the biggest combination like 9211 in python

Tags: python

```
x = [9,2,1]
l=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    p = max(x)
    l.append(p)
    x.remove(p)
print(l)
b = int(''.join(str(n) for n in l))
print(b)
```

The answer I got is 921
But if the list is [9,2,11].This won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [9,2,11]

from itertools import combinations
l=combinations(x, len(x))
print max(map(lambda k: int("".join(map(str,k))),l))
```

You can use `combinations` here.

Output:

`9211`